# Setup a graylog2 server with elasticsearch in a vagrant machine

Tags: elasticsearch, graylog2

I'm trying to Install graylog2 server on my local dev machine and encountering problems with elasticsearch setup.

My elasticsearch is installed as a service on a vagrant machine running on my dev machine. so My elasticsearch isn't installed in 127.0.0.1 but in 192.168.50.4 (the ip of the vagrant machine) I have ports 9200  forwarded from the vagrant machine but graylog2 server seems to fail to find it and stops running with a :

> ERROR: Could not successfully connect to ElasticSearch. Check that
>   your cluster state is not RED and that ElasticSearch is running
>   properly.

Adding port 9300 forwarded from the vagrant machine changed the error to:

> Caused by: org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.ChannelException:
>   Failed to bind to: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:9350

I tried this settings in graylog conf file:

> elasticsearch_network_host =192.168.50.4 
>   but that only changes the error to an exception failing to bind to
>
> Caused by: org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.ChannelException:
>   Failed to bind to: /192.168.50.4:9350     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bind(ServerBootstrap.java:272)

But didn't help.

I'll be glad for any direction what am I doing wrong (either with elastic search configuration or the vagrant or graylog2)

Thanks!

**Update** following advice by the answer below I changed the following config:

```
elasticsearch_discovery_zen_ping_multicast_enabled = false
elasticsearch_discovery_zen_ping_unicast_hosts = 192.168.50.4:9300
```

I now get this error:

```
2014-06-16 23:04:34,946 WARN : org.elasticsearch.transport.netty - [graylog2-server] Message not fully read (response) for [6] handler org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ping.unicast.UnicastZenPing$4@67bd250a, error [true], resetting
2014-06-16 23:04:36,451 WARN : org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ping.unicast - [graylog2-server] failed to send ping to [[#zen_unicast_1#][inet[/192.168.50.4:9300]]]
org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException: Failed to deserialize exception response from stream
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportSerializationException: Failed to deserialize exception response from stream
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handlerResponseError(MessageChannelHandler.java:169)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.messageReceived(MessageChannelHandler.java:123)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:310)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: failed to read class descriptor
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1603)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1622)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)

looks that graylog2 still fails to connect to elastic search in a correct way
```

**Details (update)**: graylog2-server-0.20.2, elasticsearch 1.1.0 (I think) - I can replace if that's the problem. java OpenJDK 64-Bit java version "1.7.0_55"

**More Updates (thanks @sheena)** When downgrading the elasticsearch version to 0.90.10 we got some progress but still not working:

Here is the current log:

```
2014-06-17 13:27:16,394 INFO : org.graylog2.Main - Graylog2 0.20.2 starting up. (JRE: Oracle Corporation 1.7.0_55 on Linux 3.13.0-29-generic)
2014-06-17 13:27:16,475 INFO : org.graylog2.plugin.system.NodeId - Node ID: e7245f12-2e8b-4803-9e88-7529169b5a91
2014-06-17 13:27:16,670 INFO : org.graylog2.buffers.ProcessBuffer - Initialized ProcessBuffer with ring size <1024> and wait strategy <BlockingWaitStrategy>.
2014-06-17 13:27:16,692 INFO : org.graylog2.buffers.OutputBuffer - Initialized OutputBuffer with ring size <1024> and wait strategy <BlockingWaitStrategy>.
2014-06-17 13:27:16,964 DEBUG: com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider - Number of application's worker threads is 8
2014-06-17 13:27:17,272 INFO : org.elasticsearch.node - [graylog2-server] version[0.90.10], pid[24419], build[0a5781f/2014-01-10T10:18:37Z]
2014-06-17 13:27:17,273 INFO : org.elasticsearch.node - [graylog2-server] initializing ...
2014-06-17 13:27:17,273 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.node - [graylog2-server] using home [/home/alon/Downloads/graylog2-server-0.20.2], config [/home/alon/Downloads/graylog2-server-0.20.2/config], data [[/home/alon/Downloads/graylog2-server-0.20.2/data]], logs [/home/alon/Downloads/graylog2-server-0.20.2/logs], work [/home/alon/Downloads/graylog2-server-0.20.2/work], plugins [/home/alon/Downloads/graylog2-server-0.20.2/plugins]
2014-06-17 13:27:17,281 INFO : org.elasticsearch.plugins - [graylog2-server] loaded [], sites []
2014-06-17 13:27:17,320 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.common.compress.lzf - using [UnsafeChunkDecoder] decoder
2014-06-17 13:27:18,655 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.threadpool - [graylog2-server] creating thread_pool [generic], type [cached], keep_alive [30s]
2014-06-17 13:27:18,740 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.threadpool - [graylog2-server] creating thread_pool [index], type [fixed], size [4], queue_size [200]
2014-06-17 13:27:18,744 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.threadpool - [graylog2-server] creating thread_pool [bulk], type [fixed], size [4], queue_size [50]
2014-06-17 13:27:18,745 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.threadpool - [graylog2-server] creating thread_pool [get], type [fixed], size [4], queue_size [1k]
2014-06-17 13:27:18,745 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.threadpool - [graylog2-server] creating thread_pool [search], type [fixed], size [12], queue_size [1k]
2014-06-17 13:27:18,745 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.threadpool - [graylog2-server] creating thread_pool [suggest], type [fixed], size [4], queue_size [1k]
2014-06-17 13:27:18,745 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.threadpool - [graylog2-server] creating thread_pool [percolate], type [fixed], size [4], queue_size [1k]
2014-06-17 13:27:18,746 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.threadpool - [graylog2-server] creating thread_pool [management], type [scaling], min [1], size [5], keep_alive [5m]
2014-06-17 13:27:18,747 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.threadpool - [graylog2-server] creating thread_pool [flush], type [scaling], min [1], size [2], keep_alive [5m]
2014-06-17 13:27:18,747 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.threadpool - [graylog2-server] creating thread_pool [merge], type [scaling], min [1], size [2], keep_alive [5m]
2014-06-17 13:27:18,747 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.threadpool - [graylog2-server] creating thread_pool [refresh], type [scaling], min [1], size [2], keep_alive [5m]
2014-06-17 13:27:18,748 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.threadpool - [graylog2-server] creating thread_pool [warmer], type [scaling], min [1], size [2], keep_alive [5m]
2014-06-17 13:27:18,748 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.threadpool - [graylog2-server] creating thread_pool [snapshot], type [scaling], min [1], size [2], keep_alive [5m]
2014-06-17 13:27:18,748 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.threadpool - [graylog2-server] creating thread_pool [optimize], type [fixed], size [1], queue_size [null]
2014-06-17 13:27:18,768 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty - [graylog2-server] using worker_count[8], port[9350], bind_host[null], publish_host[null], compress[false], connect_timeout[30s], connections_per_node[2/3/6/1/1], receive_predictor[512kb->512kb]
2014-06-17 13:27:18,784 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ping.unicast - [graylog2-server] using initial hosts [192.168.50.4:9300], with concurrent_connects [10]
2014-06-17 13:27:18,787 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen - [graylog2-server] using ping.timeout [3s], master_election.filter_client [true], master_election.filter_data [false]
2014-06-17 13:27:18,788 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.elect - [graylog2-server] using minimum_master_nodes [-1]
2014-06-17 13:27:18,790 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.fd - [graylog2-server] [master] uses ping_interval [1s], ping_timeout [30s], ping_retries [3]
2014-06-17 13:27:18,801 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.fd - [graylog2-server] [node  ] uses ping_interval [1s], ping_timeout [30s], ping_retries [3]
2014-06-17 13:27:18,845 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.monitor.jvm - [graylog2-server] enabled [true], last_gc_enabled [false], interval [1s], gc_threshold [{old=GcThreshold{name='old', warnThreshold=10000, infoThreshold=5000, debugThreshold=2000}, default=GcThreshold{name='default', warnThreshold=10000, infoThreshold=5000, debugThreshold=2000}, young=GcThreshold{name='young', warnThreshold=1000, infoThreshold=700, debugThreshold=400}}]
2014-06-17 13:27:18,846 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.monitor.os - [graylog2-server] Using probe [org.elasticsearch.monitor.os.JmxOsProbe@7b01e044] with refresh_interval [1s]
2014-06-17 13:27:18,849 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.monitor.process - [graylog2-server] Using probe [org.elasticsearch.monitor.process.JmxProcessProbe@3103c203] with refresh_interval [1s]
2014-06-17 13:27:18,854 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.monitor.jvm - [graylog2-server] Using refresh_interval [1s]
2014-06-17 13:27:18,854 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.monitor.network - [graylog2-server] Using probe [org.elasticsearch.monitor.network.JmxNetworkProbe@1cc7580f] with refresh_interval [5s]
2014-06-17 13:27:18,857 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.monitor.network - [graylog2-server] net_info
host [stox-alonisser]
vboxnet0    display_name [vboxnet0]
        address [/fe80:0:0:0:800:27ff:fe00:0%4] [/192.168.50.1] 
        mtu [1500] multicast [true] ptp [false] loopback [false] up [true] virtual [false]
wlan0   display_name [wlan0]
        address [/fe80:0:0:0:e8b:fdff:fe62:dc9d%3] [/192.168.20.107] 
        mtu [1500] multicast [true] ptp [false] loopback [false] up [true] virtual [false]
lo  display_name [lo]
        address [/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1] [/127.0.0.1] 
        mtu [65536] multicast [false] ptp [false] loopback [true] up [true] virtual [false]

2014-06-17 13:27:18,858 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.monitor.fs - [graylog2-server] Using probe [org.elasticsearch.monitor.fs.JmxFsProbe@2c8807d7] with refresh_interval [1s]
2014-06-17 13:27:19,196 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.indices.store - [graylog2-server] using indices.store.throttle.type [MERGE], with index.store.throttle.max_bytes_per_sec [20mb]
2014-06-17 13:27:19,204 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.cache.memory - [graylog2-server] using bytebuffer cache with small_buffer_size [1kb], large_buffer_size [1mb], small_cache_size [10mb], large_cache_size [500mb], direct [true]
2014-06-17 13:27:19,220 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.script - [graylog2-server] using script cache with max_size [500], expire [null]
2014-06-17 13:27:19,234 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.cluster.routing.allocation.decider - [graylog2-server] using node_concurrent_recoveries [2], node_initial_primaries_recoveries [4]
2014-06-17 13:27:19,235 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.cluster.routing.allocation.decider - [graylog2-server] using [cluster.routing.allocation.allow_rebalance] with [indices_all_active]
2014-06-17 13:27:19,236 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.cluster.routing.allocation.decider - [graylog2-server] using [cluster_concurrent_rebalance] with [2]
2014-06-17 13:27:19,243 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.gateway.local - [graylog2-server] using initial_shards [quorum], list_timeout [30s]
2014-06-17 13:27:19,424 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.indices.recovery - [graylog2-server] using max_bytes_per_sec[20mb], concurrent_streams [3], file_chunk_size [512kb], translog_size [512kb], translog_ops [1000], and compress [true]
2014-06-17 13:27:19,486 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.indices.memory - [graylog2-server] using index_buffer_size [265.4mb], with min_shard_index_buffer_size [4mb], max_shard_index_buffer_size [512mb], shard_inactive_time [30m]
2014-06-17 13:27:19,487 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.indices.cache.filter - [graylog2-server] using [node] weighted filter cache with size [20%], actual_size [530.8mb], expire [null], clean_interval [1m]
2014-06-17 13:27:19,489 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.indices.fielddata.cache - [graylog2-server] using size [-1] [-1b], expire [null]
2014-06-17 13:27:19,507 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.gateway.local.state.meta - [graylog2-server] using gateway.local.auto_import_dangled [YES], with gateway.local.dangling_timeout [2h]
2014-06-17 13:27:19,511 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.bulk.udp - [graylog2-server] using enabled [false], host [null], port [9700-9800], bulk_actions [1000], bulk_size [5mb], flush_interval [5s], concurrent_requests [4]
2014-06-17 13:27:19,514 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.cluster.routing.allocation.decider - [graylog2-server] using node_concurrent_recoveries [2], node_initial_primaries_recoveries [4]
2014-06-17 13:27:19,514 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.cluster.routing.allocation.decider - [graylog2-server] using [cluster.routing.allocation.allow_rebalance] with [indices_all_active]
2014-06-17 13:27:19,515 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.cluster.routing.allocation.decider - [graylog2-server] using [cluster_concurrent_rebalance] with [2]
2014-06-17 13:27:19,516 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.cluster.routing.allocation.decider - [graylog2-server] using node_concurrent_recoveries [2], node_initial_primaries_recoveries [4]
2014-06-17 13:27:19,516 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.cluster.routing.allocation.decider - [graylog2-server] using [cluster.routing.allocation.allow_rebalance] with [indices_all_active]
2014-06-17 13:27:19,516 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.cluster.routing.allocation.decider - [graylog2-server] using [cluster_concurrent_rebalance] with [2]
2014-06-17 13:27:19,528 INFO : org.elasticsearch.node - [graylog2-server] initialized
2014-06-17 13:27:19,529 INFO : org.elasticsearch.node - [graylog2-server] starting ...
2014-06-17 13:27:19,552 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.netty.channel.socket.nio.SelectorUtil - Using select timeout of 500
2014-06-17 13:27:19,552 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.netty.channel.socket.nio.SelectorUtil - Epoll-bug workaround enabled = false
2014-06-17 13:27:19,618 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty - [graylog2-server] Bound to address [/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9350]
2014-06-17 13:27:19,622 INFO : org.elasticsearch.transport - [graylog2-server] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9350]}, publish_address {inet[/192.168.20.107:9350]}
2014-06-17 13:27:19,658 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty - [graylog2-server] connected to node [[#zen_unicast_1#][inet[/192.168.50.4:9300]]]
2014-06-17 13:27:22,628 WARN : org.elasticsearch.discovery - [graylog2-server] waited for 3s and no initial state was set by the discovery
2014-06-17 13:27:22,628 INFO : org.elasticsearch.discovery - [graylog2-server] graylog2/vWsYLp5JQoOJMva0FZgRsA
2014-06-17 13:27:22,629 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.gateway - [graylog2-server] can't wait on start for (possibly) reading state from gateway, will do it asynchronously
2014-06-17 13:27:22,629 INFO : org.elasticsearch.node - [graylog2-server] started
2014-06-17 13:27:22,642 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty - [graylog2-server] disconnected from [[#zen_unicast_1#][inet[/192.168.50.4:9300]]]
2014-06-17 13:27:22,644 DEBUG: org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen - [graylog2-server] filtered ping responses: (filter_client[true], filter_data[false])
    --> target [[Crimson Daffodil][vPHcWzoCQteDG19hofaayA][inet[/10.0.2.15:9300]]], master [[Crimson Daffodil][vPHcWzoCQteDG19hofaayA][inet[/10.0.2.15:9300]]]
2014-06-17 13:27:27,634 ERROR: org.graylog2.Main -
```

Comment: I believe I have figured this out. Will come back to post an answer.

Answer (score 7):

elasticsearch_network_host is not what you think. It is about the elasticsearch /client/ within graylog, and not the elasticsearch server you want to connect with. So graylog is trying to listen on 192.168.50.4 which isn't a valid IP address on the graylog system (your dev machine).

You most likely want to set these variables in graylog2 config:

```
elasticsearch_discovery_zen_ping_multicast_enabled = false
elasticsearch_discovery_zen_ping_unicast_hosts = 192.168.50.4:9300
```

Here is where I got stuck, but that was because I had elasticsearch 1.0 installed when I needed 0.90. I'll now more once my puppet/vagrant stack finishes re-provisioning. =)

EDIT: Mine is working now.

Comment: Thanks @sheena, Looks closer to working but not yet..   this still doesn't work for me. Updated the question with the results..

Comment: What version of elasticsearch and graylog2 are you using?

Comment: And which version of java!

Comment: Added versions in the question. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you've chopped your error stacktrace off?

Comment: i do see this: disconnected from [[#zen_unicast_1#][inet[/192.168.50.4:9300]]] I would check elasticsearch to see what logs it is spitting out.

Comment: Actually this comes few lines after a "connected to node" line. checking the logs wasn't helpful at all.. no clues there, at least for my inexperienced eyes. What am I looking for.

Comment: You are listening on '10.0.2.15' in graylog2 . I would check that and try to ensure you are listening  on the right ip. It could be any number of configuration options, so posting your config files for graylog2 and elasticsearch may be your best option. Also check iptables to ensure you aren't firewalled in your VM.

Comment: this is the ip inside the vagrant machine (the one known in the outside as 192.168.50.4)

Comment: can you please post a gist with a working configuration? I'm must be missing somethign obvious

Comment: You have two addresses within your vagrant machine, 10.0.2.15 and 192.168.50.4. These are two separate network addresses so you have to bind on the right one.

Comment: I'll try that. I'll also award the bounty for your great help.
Not sure What do you mean in "Binding to the right one" Bind how? Where?

Comment: A network program can 'bind' on an IP address on a system, and graylog2 is bound to 10.0.2.15. This means that communication can only go to addresses within the 10.0.2.* range or anything that routes to it. This means nothing within your local network can access anything listening on 10.0.2.15.